# nonlinear subblock solver in simulink

Tags: simulink

I would like to implement a system of nonlinear ODE subblocks in simulink.
The global solver would have to wait for the valid result of the subblocks.

Any ideas for possible approaches?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a custom block -- most likely an m-code S-Function, but possibly a MATLAB Function Block -- that implements the code for solving your ODE.

Since Simulink will wait for that block to complete before continuing its time stepping there's nothing additional you need to do for this to happen.

Comment: Thanks Phil, S-functions are the way to go.

Comment: @bardo Code generation support was added for for the MATLAB solvers `ode45` and `ode23` in R2014b. Those may save you some implementation time if they are relevant to your problem.